# Send results as csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am trying to get SQL Server Agent to send this as an email

All I get is errors.  It works without the @query parameter but I don't see the issue.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'e-automate mail',
     @recipients = 'jbalter@seamlesssolutions.com',
     @subject = 'on hold customers',
     @body='Customers on Hold in E-automate',
     @query = 'SELECT CC.CustomerID AS 'E-auto Number',
                      CC.TextVal AS 'Autotask Number',
                      ARC.CustomerName
                  FROM [CoCopeco].[dbo].[ARCustomerCustomProperties] CC
                  INNER JOIN [CoCopeco].[dbo].[ARCustomers] ARC  ON ARC.CustomerID = CC.CustomerID
                  WHERE ShAttributeID = '2043' 
                    AND ARC.OnHoldCodeID IS NOT NULL
                    AND DATALENGTH (CC.TextVal) > 0 ' ,
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
    @query_result_separator = ','
```

Comment: Which error do you get ? Besides that: I don't understand the meaning of the title you gave this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to replace single quotes with additional single quotes within the @Query parameter tab i.e. replacing ' with ''.

Put the @Query value as shown below -

```
@query = 'SELECT CC.CustomerID AS ''E-auto Number'',
              CC.TextVal AS ''Autotask Number'',
              ARC.CustomerName
          FROM [CoCopeco].[dbo].[ARCustomerCustomProperties] CC
          INNER JOIN [CoCopeco].[dbo].[ARCustomers] ARC  ON ARC.CustomerID = CC.CustomerID
          WHERE ShAttributeID = ''2043'' 
            AND ARC.OnHoldCodeID IS NOT NULL
            AND DATALENGTH (CC.TextVal) > 0 '
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Kindly mark it as answered so that other questions can be tended to.